# Visual Studio 2015 application is in break mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, visual-studio

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Web application with C# and .NET 4.6.1.

I have a solution with several projects in it. Every project compiles fine.

All projects do target the same .NET version (4.6.1), I deleted the *obj* and *bin* folders as well as the nugget packages from each project, cleaned and built each project in the solution independently. After all even cloned a fresh version of the repository from GIT.

Nevertheless, when I try to launch the application, I'm always getting the following error exception:

**System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**

[image: the application is in break mode vs 2015]

Have anyone of you ever faced this error? Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you running the code in debug mode (Debug in Visual Studio and your web.config has `<compilation debug="true" />`? You might get a better exception. Otherwise, can you test the code on another machine to rule out environmental factors?

Comment: open and view the stack to find where is come from